# how do you make a menubar appear when crossing a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

To start of I am a beginner,
I want to make a menubar appear when I scroll down the page and cross a sertain div (when the actual menubar on top of my page is not visible anymore) This site has the perfect example for my problem: http://lenssenmannenmode.nl

When you start scrolling down this page and the headermenu isn't visible anymore a black transparant menu pops up at the top of this page.

Thanks in advance and pls help! :)

Comment: Perhaps you could show us your layout for the general page, then perhaps one can help you develop a menu bar that pops up when you reach a certain point (x pixels) as you scroll down the page.

Comment: yeah I know but then I have to post my whole page, while itis most likely a commonly used method? Could you try explain it with like "some div here" etc.?

Comment: Look into jQuery - once you learn how jQuery works (or even javascript) look into `.scrollTo()` When the window's scroll position is greater than X, show the menu.

Comment: cmon still didnt got an usable answer, I did searched alot of tutorials before asking but couldn't find the right one srry but pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following do demonstrates how to let the menu bar appear when a user have scrolled past 400px on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Fire this function when a user scrolls
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        // If the user scrolled past 400 pixels on this page show the menu, else hide it.
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 400){
            $("#your-menu").slideDown();
        }else{
            $("#your-menu").slideUp();
        }
    });

});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6WsHR/3/) for an example.